# Android Espresso: Sliding Tabs with RecyclerViews in every tab

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a sliding tabs app, with recyclerview in every tab.
I am testing the app using [Android Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html). I want to click on one of the recyclerview item. when i do this:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(2, click()));
```

I get this exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: com.uriel.frankel:id/recyclerView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

any Ideas?

Comment: why dont you just add listeners to your items?

Comment: You have a `RecyclerView` with an `Adapter` which has an inner `ViewHoler` class right?

Comment: I am talking about UI Unit testing with Android Espresso.

Comment: oh sorry then i missed that one

Comment: My mistake. I edited the the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, i guess you are using the same xml file for every `RecyclerView` in your tabs. Hence all your `RecyclerView's` have the same ID. So you can't refer to your `RecyclerView's` using your ID's.

So either give every `RecyclerView` it's own ID or try searching with any other `ViewMatcher` like `withText("any specific text in your recyclers")`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html) you may find methods that will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create the `ViewHolder` matcher to match specific item inside `RecyclerView`. Then you'll be able to use `PositionableRecyclerViewAction` like `scrollToHolder(...)` for example:

```
public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withMessageSubjectInViewHolder(String itemSubject) {
        Checks.checkNotNull(itemSubject);
        return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                MyRecyclerViewItemAdapter.MyViewHolder>(MyRecyclerViewItemAdapter.MyViewHolder.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(MyRecyclerViewItemAdapter.MyViewHolder holder) {
                boolean isMatches = false;

                if (!(holder.subject == null)) {
                    isMatches = ((itemSubject.equals(holder.subject.getText().toString()))
                            && (holder.subject.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE));
                }
                return isMatches;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with message subject: " + itemSubject);
            }
        };
    }
```

And this is how I use it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_recycler_view_id)).perform(scrollToHolder(withMessageSubjectInViewHolder(unique_message_subject)));
onView(withText(unique_message_subject)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```